# Nested generators and yield from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have an nested object, `a`, and want to apply some type of filter on each of its sub-containers:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 7, 8]]
```

A function to keep the nested structure but filter to only even elements would look like:

```
def nested_filter(obj):
    res = []
    for sub_obj in obj:
        even = [i for i in sub_obj if i % 2 == 0]
        res.append(even)
    return res

nested_filter(a)
# [[2], [4, 6], [8]]
```

But I would like to create an equivalent generator that uses some form a nested `yield` to maintain the nested structure of `a`.

This, for illustration, is exactly what I do not want because it flattens `a`:

```
def nested_yield(obj):
    """Will flatten the nested structure of obj."""
    for sub_obj in obj:
        for i in sub_obj:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                yield i

list(nested_yield(a))
# [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

My understanding was that `yield from`, [introduced in Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator), might allow for nesting that retains the structure of the passed object.  But apparently I am misinterpreting:

```
def gen1(obj):
    for sub_obj in obj:
        yield from gen2(sub_obj)


def gen2(sub_obj):
    for i in sub_obj:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            yield i

list(gen1(a))
# [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

So, is there any way I can use two generator functions (i.e. not create intermediate lists) so that calling the generator would give me this:

```
list(nested_generator(a))
# [[2], [4, 6], [8]]
```

Comment: You'll still have to yield lists from `gen1`

Comment: From the `list(nested_generator(a))` statement it appears you want `nested_generator(a)` to return a list of sublists, which implies that the data from second-level lists requires creating a `list` to return (with the filtered elements removed). The items from the sublists could be obtained via a generator, but there's no way to avoid creating a temporary sub`list` to hold and return the results.

Comment: Got it @martineau.  Sometimes "no can do" is a correct answer in itself.

Comment: True, I guess that's what I'm saying, but see no need to also post it as a formal answer. I see you've noticed that the one answer you've gotten so far creates temporary lists to `yield`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your `nested_generator` to return a list of sublists.  In this case, you cannot get around creating temporary lists at the inner level.

So, your best option is to yield the filtered list:

```
>>> def nested_filter(L):
    for l in L:
        yield [i for i in l if i % 2 == 0]


>>> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 7, 8]]
>>> list(nested_filter(a))
[[2], [4, 6], [8]]
```

If you want to use a second generator to filter your sub-list, you can convert the iterator returned to a list and `yield` that as well:

```
>>> def generator_filter(L):
    for n in L:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            yield n


>>> def nested_filter(L):
    for l in L:
        yield list(generator_filter(l))


>>> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 7, 8]]
>>> list(nested_generator(a))
[[2], [4, 6], [8]]
```